# Can someone tell me the source of this story diagram image?

Tags: structure, graphics

This image was found on a University of Hawaii Cinematic & Digital Narrative Production course and the professor found the image on Google search.

Although the plot structure is not unique, the original material might a great source of plot planning information.

[image: Story diagram]

Comment: Did you try Google reverse image search?

Comment: Yes, definitely. I also tried to search for some of the key terms in the image.

Comment: How do you know the professor found the image on google search?

Comment: I emailed the professor before posting. It was a much better chance at finding the source. Oddly, the professor said he found the image on a Google search.

Comment: Well, I am afraid, as my answers says, that as of now the image does not exist on the internet before the professor placed it on his site.

Comment: That's a good point. Hopefully someone will recognize it...

Comment: In this case, even if someone would recognize it, it would not do you much good. Like I said, wherever it was when the professor found it, its not there anymore. So the text/theory that accompanied it, is also not there anymore. Which means you're left with just the image to work with ^^

Comment: This is very interesting. Sorry for the lack of help, but this seems like something one could write stories about.

Comment: On this diagram, "Inc." is likely to be "Incident" (or "Inciting Incident"), but anyone know what "Hk" is? My guess is "Hero known" (as in, the hero, in his ordinary "known" world is introduced), but any other ideas?

Answer (score 6):

**The origin of the image is forever lost.**

The oldest mention from the image, is from 17 May 2009, indeed from the website of the university you mentioned. Before that, the image can't be found anywhere.

I wonder if the professor did actually find it somewhere, and unless you could ask him, there is no way to find out where he has it from. Every other mention of the image is linked back to the university site.

Unless there is someone from that time around that specifically remembers this image (which is gonna be a long stretch) or by accident you find the creator, I am afraid you will never find out where it's from.